# res.json(data) displays the json directly in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, frontend, backend

When sending a json object from the backend (nodejs) to the frontend using res.json(data) (data being the name of the json), it displays directly in the browser instead of being sent to the javascript in the front end as a variable.

Here is the code I'm using

- in NodeJS (using express and mysql):

```
app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    db.query('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?', [req.body.mail], async (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (result[0]) {
            console.log('Mail already used') // This gets logged properly
            var data = {
                status: 'error',
                error: 'This email is already being used'
            }
            res.json(data);
...
```

- in the front end (vanilla Javascript):

```
const form = document.getElementById('register')
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    const formData = new FormData(form)
    fetch("/register", {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            document.getElementById('error').style.display = "block"
            document.getElementById('error').innerText = data.error
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error)
        })
```

- in the HTML:

```
        <form id="register" action="/register" method="POST" >
            <div class="txt name">
                <input type="text" name="name" id='name' required>
                <label>name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="txt mail">
                <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" required>
                <label>Mail</label>
            </div>
            <div class="txt password">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
                <label>Password</label>
            </div>
            <div class="txt confirm">
                <input type="password" name="confirm" id="confirm" required>
                <label>Confirm Password</label>
            </div>
            <div class="btn">
                <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Register">
            </div>
```

[This is what's getting shown in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iY9Jk.png)

*Btw I want to use vanilla javascript and html because it's for a school project*

Comment: Is the event listener for the form called at all?

Comment: Move the listener to the click handler of the submit button.

Comment: @qqilihq yes I forgot to include the `const form = document.getElementById('register')`

Comment: @DaveNewton — Really not. That’s rather less reliable.

Comment: Odds are that `form.addEventListener` is throwing an error. You need to check the console and debug it.

Comment: Hmm. Or the JS never loads into the browser.

Comment: @Quentin Oh yeah I found an error saying `TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.`. I think the fetch (which is async) starts and the user is redirected to another page before the fetch finished. I have no clue how to solve this

Comment: A network error shouldn't cause you to be redirected. The symptom you're describing happens if the form posts normally to `/register` instead of using `fetch()`.

Comment: If you put `console.log("Sending fetch")` in the event listener, do you see that in the console?

Comment: @Barmar before the fetch yes, in the `.then(data => {...` no

Comment: What if you change `action="/register"` to `action="#"`?

Comment: Surely the `event.preventDefault()` call does not work, for some reason you will have to find out, and then the normal form submission renders the json response